# Align figure captions left in R quarto - knitting to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto, figcaption

I simply want the caption for my figures aligned left, rather than centre as the default is set.

How do I achieve this?

````
---
title: "Figure Caption Test"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| label: fig-test
#| fig-cap: "This is a test caption"

plot(rnorm(100))
```

See @fig-test.
````

Comment: Please include a [mre] when you ask questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\captionsetup` from the [`caption`](https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf) package. Since quarto loads the caption package automatically, just tweak the options through the `\captionsetup` command.

So to align the caption to left, you need to use `justification=raggedright`<sup>1</sup>. Also, use `singlelinecheck=false` so that caption gets left-aligned even if it is a one-line caption <sup>2</sup>.

````
---
title: "Figure Caption Test"
format: pdf
include-before-body:
  - text: |
      \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
---

```{r}
#| label: fig-test
#| fig-cap: "This is a test caption"

plot(rnorm(100))
```

See @fig-test.
````

---

[image: rendered output with left aligned figure caption]

---

<sup>1</sup> See section 2.2 page 8 of the [caption package documentation](https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf) for details

<sup>2</sup> see page 9 for details.